# How to run a R script through Python by passing command line arguments

Tags: python, r, command-line, subprocess

I am trying to run a R script through Python by passing command line arguments. I am using this piece of code :

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(["Rscript", "modelcriteria.R", "--args","model_selection_criteria.csv"])
```

I am encountering this error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
...
In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file '--args': No such file or directory
Execution halted.
```

All I want to do is to pass the `model_selection_criteria.csv` file to my R script in Python environment. Can anyone please point out the problem in my code or suggest an alternative solution to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error itself tells you the truth. Try removing `"--args"`

Comment: yeah thanks I have tried it, runs now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run modelcriteria.R from the command line, what command do you use? I'm not familiar with R but from the error and the  [popen docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), I don't think you need the `'--args'`.

```
proc=subprocess.Popen(["Rscript", "modelcriteria.R","model_selection_criteria.csv"])
```

Should be the equivalent of `Rscript modelcriteria.R model_selection_criteria.csv` at the command line.

Comment: Yes , I am not familar too with these type of operations. your answer helps.